# How to move footnotes to next column?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

How can I move footnotes to the next column? I need the vertical space at the bottom for a table, otherwise it gets split in 2.

[image: How do I move this block of footnotes to the other column?]

I tried the footnote paragraph's **Keep options** and it didn't pan out no matter what I selected. Also, if I make the table non-breaking it just jumps to the next column.

And I would've gotten away with it too, if it wasn't for you meddling footnotes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a total hack but a testament to how crappy footnotes are handled in InDesign.

What I do is put an invisible footnote in the column I want it to appear. Then I just use a footnote superscript styling of where I want it to be visibly anchored. I was hoping for a better way and that's how I found this thread, but it seems like I'm stuck with my inelegant method.

Maybe someone else has a better method but I haven't found it.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

After making the footnote and apply a Paragraph Style to it, make a Find/replace with a GREP:

- Find a space after the character number xxx `.{300}`
- Replace it for a Page Break `~P`
- Just in the Footnote Paragraph Style

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can’t.

The beginning of a footnote will always be forced to appear on the same page as the footnote anchor. This is hardcoded into InDesign and, unless someone has found some clever method I’m not aware of, cannot be overridden.

The only way you can do it here is to make a fake footnote—but remember to make sure you adjust the following footnote’s number accordingly, and to make sure reflowed text doesn’t end up moving the fake footnote somewhere it doesn’t belong.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the absolute wrong way to do it, but I converted them to endnotes, and moved that text box up to the page where my table is.